# why is my loop variable not alive after 1 iteration?

Tags: bash

I have this code

```
for p in "abra/cadabra reach/out"
do
        r="$HOME/x/$p"
        echo $r
done
```

But it only produces this:

```
/Users/terrencemonroebrannon/x/abra/cadabra reach/out
```

Not

```
/Users/terrencemonroebrannon/x/abra/cadabra /Users/terrencemonroebrannon/x/reach/out
```

as I would expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have placed your two items in quotes, which bash interprets as a single token.  That's what quotes are for.  You would get the behavior you describe if you were to remove the quotes:

```
for p in abra/cadabra reach/out
do
        r="$HOME/x/$p"
        echo $r
done
```

Gives me:

```
/Users/lars/x/abra/cadabra
/Users/lars/x/reach/out
```

Answer (score 2):

bash will see `"abra/cadabra reach/out"` as one token.
Quotes are not needed.

```
for p in abra/cadabra reach/out
do
        r="$HOME/x/$p"
        echo $r
done
```

Comment: Also note that if you have spaces in the path names themselves, those *will* need to be quoted individually: `for p in "path one" "path two"`